# Shadow for a background image

Tags: html, css

I have a `span` element as follows -

```
<span class="tick"></span>
```

This basically generates a "tick" for a checkbox.

The CSS is as follows -

```
input[type="checkbox"] + span > span.tick {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -3px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/content/dam/oe_tick.png);
    background-size: 18px;
    background-position: 3px 1px;
}
```

I want to add a shadow around the image - `/content/dam/oe_tick.png`.
Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. One way to achieve this is by using CSS filters (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp).

```
span.tick {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 0px rgba(244, 247, 249, 1));
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 2px 0px rgba(244, 247, 249, 1));
}
```

I was successfully able to add a shadow around the tick mark.